# Best way to check a char sequence on a line

Tags: java, loops, dictionary

I have an input stream which I want to use to read specific messages whether it is contained in the map, e.g.: `you must consider : Invalid card number.` // this is the line.

I want to check whether this line contains the 'Invalid card number' key of the map.

We have to iterate through the map and checks whether the line contains the message.

```
String line = "you must consider : Invalid card number.";
for (String key : map) {
    if(line.contains(key)) {
        throw new Exception(key.value());
    }
}
```

But then we have to iterate through this map for every line of the stream.

Is this a good practice?

Comment: What's the problem with iteration? The application is too slow?

Comment: you mean "whether" not "weather"

Comment: What is the size of the file? How many lines does it contain?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you have an input string and want to verify if it contains any of the strings in your predefined list. There is no better way than checking them one by one (except for maybe some simple checks on string length).

Comment: if the map size is 100 then we have to iterate through 100 of times. then if the stream size is 2000 then what will happen?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said in comments, yes, this is probably the only way you can achieve this.

On the other hand your `for statement` should look like this (assuming your map is a java.util.Map):

```
for (String key : map.values()) {
```